# How to pull HEAD inside working directory without committing first

Tags: git

Usually, when I work on a big feature, I often pull HEAD in order to avoid a painful merge at the end. However, git doesn't allow me to do so without committing my files needing a merge. If I remember well, this was possible with Mercurial.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
...
...
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: why not commit or stash the changes?

Comment: Because I don't want to commit unfinished work, I only want to get commits from HEAD and merge them with my code.

Comment: Although stashing makes a commit (actually at least *two* commits), the stash commit is not on any branch and will not affect your rebase or merge.  You may have to do another merge to apply the stash later, though (depending on how different your in-progress code is from the result of a rebase-or-merge with your upstream).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the message says, you can `git stash` your changes. After pulling, run `git stash apply` to bring them back into your working tree. You are probably having to solve some conflicts then.

After that, you can run `git stash drop`. A good practice is to add the stash number to the drop command, you can see it in `git stash list` and input it in the form `git stash drop stash@{0}`. However, if you haven’t used stash yet, just `git stash drop` is safe.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Actually, I though stash meant getting rid of all local changes. Thanks!

Comment: @Lucas No, that’s called _reset_ in Git terminology.

Comment: `git stash pop` means `git stash apply && git stash drop`: i.e., apply, and then if the apply works, drop; but if the apply fails (needs a merge for instance), keep the stash.  I recommend `apply` instead of `pop` since sometimes (albeit rarely) the apply works, but doesn't do what you wanted, in which case having the original stash is sometimes somewhat useful.  (It's rarely that big a deal though.)  TL;DR version (if not too late :-) ): you mean `apply` then `drop`, or `pop` and don't drop (unless the pop fails).

Comment: @torek Good point. I changed my `pop` to `apply` since we discuss the case when we are expecting conflicts. `pop` doesn’t have any advantage in such a case, only that it’s shorter. :-) BTW you can still access the original stash after `pop` using the hash displayed in the drop phase. It’s generally a good practice to keep the window opened for a while because of these hashes (also moving away from detached HEAD etc.).

Comment: @Melebius: yes, you can keep using the SHA-1 "true name" (as I call it) for any object until the object gets garbage-collected.  Having dropped the reference, though, the object is now "gc-eligible".  If you accidentally dropped a stash and realize you want to save it, you can use `git tag` to tag the hash, which will make it stick around.  (Also, if the stash is under 14 days old, the `prune` step of `git gc` will leave it around anyway, so the risk of losing stuff is really quite low :-) )